# Limit of a function of two variable $f(x,y).$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to find the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{3}y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{6}+y^{2})}$$ i tried it as follow

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{3}y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{6}+y^{2})}=\lim (y)(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}})(\frac{x^{2}}{x^{6}+y^{2}})\leq \lim (y)(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}})(\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}})=\lim (\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}})(\frac{x^{2}}{y})=0 $

Comment: The term $\frac{x^2}{x^6 + y^2}$ is not bounded.

Comment: ok thanks....if possible can you give some hint to solve it...

Comment: Does this limit exist or not?

Comment: thats i don't know ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you approach $(0,0)$ via the line the $x=0$ then $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{3}y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{6}+y^{2})}=0.$$

Now if you approach $(0,0)$ via the curve $(y^{1/3},y)$ then 
$\dfrac{x^{3}y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{6}+y^{2})}=\dfrac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^{2/3}+y^{2}}(2y^{2})}=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{y^{2/3}+y^{2}}}$
and so there $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^{3}y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}(x^{6}+y^{2})}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you consider the limit along the curve $y = x^3$.